# Integration test `enterText` method not working on profile or release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, integration-testing, flutter-integration-test

Test passes in debug mode but not in profile or release mode. It does not enter text when calling `enterText` even if the input has focus. In debug mode it enters the text without problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/87990), or more exactly a [difference](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/89703) between how integration-tests work in debug vs profile or release.

### TLDR

Basically if you're not in debug mode you have to call binding.testTextInput.register() in order for `tester.enterText` to work.

```
  final binding = IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() as IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding;

// Necessary for being able to enterText when not in debug mode 
  binding.testTextInput.register();
```

This will permit to call `enterText` during integration testing.
As a [caveat](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/87990#issuecomment-1003675826) this will disable the use of real keyboards during the test, but most of the times that is not the case.

#### Why does that happens?

Because in debug mode this is permitted via an assert which don't work on profile or release modes. [See source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/619121b095d9b506451387bde027038e7a986ab8/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart#L1430-L1444)